# how to apply a function to a certain container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have build a little function which returns a jQuery plugin applied to a certain element, as in the following example:

```
var initiate_shop = function(shop_navigation, options, callback) {

    var default_settings = {
        containerID     : "",
        first           : false,
        previous        : false,
        next            : false,
        last            : false,
        startPage       : 1,
        perPage         : 8,
        midRange        : 15,
        startRange      : 1,
        endRange        : 1,
        keyBrowse       : true,
        scrollBrowse    : false,
        pause           : 0,
        clickStop       : true,
        delay           : 50,
        direction       : "auto",
        animation       : "fadeInUp",
        fallback        : 400,
        minHeight       : true,
        callback        : function(pages, items){
            if(typeof callback == 'function') {
                callback.call(this);
            }
        }
    };

    var settings = $.extend(default_settings, options);

    return $(shop_navigation).jPages(settings);
};
```

My question would be, how could I use that `initiate_shop` function like this:

```
$("shop_navigation").initiate_shop( ... );
```

Instead of using it like this:

```
initiate_shop(shop_navigation, ... );
```

Also, how can I define arguments for the callback function, in my situation I have two objects as arguments for the callback function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to create a jQuery plugin. Extend the `$.fn` object with your function, and you will be able to access your container with the `this` keyword from within the function.

```
$.fn.initiate_shop = function(options, callback) {
    ...
    return this.jPages(settings);
};
```

Note that your call `$('shop_navigation')` is not a valid selector, unless you're looking for an element named `shop_navigation`. Did you intend to write `$('#shop_navigation')`?

The reason I'm asking is that you might equally well write

```
$('.shop_navigation').initiate_shop(options, callback);
```

It is up to your plugin to deal with supporting multiple elements being passed in `this`.

---

The way you're currently calling your callback, using `.call`, is useful if you want to specify what the context, i.e. the `this` keyword, is in your callback function.

Consider that your callback looks like this:

```
var callback = function(pages, items) {
   console.log(this);
   console.log(pages);
   console.log(items);
};
```

If you don't care what the `this` keyword is within your callback function, you could simply call the function as

```
callback(pages, items);
```

If you want to manually set the calling context, you may use `.call` or `.apply`. You can still pass arguments to the function:

```
// first argument defines calling context
// all others passed as arguments to function
callback.call(this, pages, items);
```

or

```
// first argument defines calling context
// second argument defines entire arguments collection
callback.apply(this, [pages, items]);
```

In your case, if `callback` variable will only ever be a function, or undefined, and you're not adding any additional logic, as it is right now, you'd get away with just:

```
var default_settings = {
    ...
    callback: callback
};
```

Comment: Oh, so making another plugin out of it would be the only option wouldn't it ?

Comment: Well `$('#shop_navigation')` will return a jQuery object, so if you want jQuery objects to have a function called `initiate_shop` then yes, how to create a plugin is effectively what you're asking :)

Comment: No, the `shop_navigation` is in fact a `div`, but I defined it as a `var shop_navigation = $(window).find('.shop-navigation');`. All right then, I'll make a jQuery plugin if there is no other option. But if you don't mind, can you tell me how I would go about the second part of my question ? The one with the arguments for the callback function ?

Comment: So my final version of the plugin would look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rcex9/ ?

Comment: That looks about right. Notice: in your fiddle, the value of `callback` is being overwritten. The callback you pass to the plugin will never be used. You can remove that `callback` definition inside the plugin entirely, to use the value that's being passed.